# Ошибка в Contacts form 7 : The response is not a valid JSON response

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

При отправке формы появляется ошибка:

{code: 'invalid_json', message: 'The response is not a valid JSON response.'}
code
:
"invalid_json"
message
:
"The response is not a valid JSON response."

Форма на почту приходит[image: ошибка]

[image: где падает]

Не приходит сообщение об успешной отправке или ошибке, падает как на скрине. Как исправить?

Comment: Посмотри внимательно на адрес на скрине - у тебя дичь в домене.

Comment: Какой-нибудь лишний вывод в php. Что во вкладке Network? https://i.imgur.com/fao3HSq.png